# Finding the Pushout

Tags: category-theory

This is a simple question. Suppose I have this diagram

[image]

And I want to find the pushout. I know that if you put $A \cup B$, the diagram will be both a pullback and a pushout. Now for

[image]

How can I 'find the pushout'? I was thinking about using a pair of adjoint functors with the forgetefull functor, but I'm not quite sure how it would work.

Comment: The category you're in really matters.

Comment: @Randall, is absolutely correct. What kind of objects are $X$ and $Y_i.$ What kind of morphisms are you assuming?

Comment: I apologize. I'm in the category of Sets.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_{1}\sqcup Y_{2}$ be the coproduct with injections $i_{1}:Y_{1}\to Y_{1}\sqcup Y_{2}$
and $i_{1}:Y_{2}\to Y_{1}\sqcup Y_{2}$.

If $f:X\to Y_1$ and $g:X\to Y_1$ are the arrows in your diagram then let $c:Y_{1}\sqcup Y_{2}\to Z$ be a coequalizer of $i_1\circ f:X\to Y_{1}\sqcup Y_{2}$ and $i_2\circ g:X\to Y_{1}\sqcup Y_{2}$.

Then $\bar{f}=c\circ i_2:X_2\to Z$ and $\bar{g}=c\circ i_2:X_1\to Z$ will make the diagram a pushout square.